# Should WCF Web service be signed to install on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2012-r2

Can't seem to find a definitive answer here.

Is it requirement to sign a C# .Net 4.5 WCF web service to run in a production environment on a Windows Server 2012 R2?

When I say 'sign', I mean, in the property tabs of the project, there's an option to 'Sign the assembly'. Must this happen for proper installation?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on your requirement, I think you are talking about  securing WCF services with certificates. Is it so?

Comment: No, it's optional, unless you want to add some dependencies to GAC. In this case you have to sign these libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Signing the assembly' is optional, when you reference a strong-named assembly, you can expect certain benefits, such as versioning and naming protection, strong-named assemblies can be installed in the Global Assembly Cache.

Keep assembly private and locate assembly in the application directory unless sharing an assembly is explicitly required or you need certain benefits.